# Minizinc SCIP Ubuntu

Tags: minizinc

I really appreciate if any of you can guide me to solve this issue.

I am trying to install additional solvers, I downloaded SCIP and install it, however, when I run it, it finishes without an OUTPUT.

If I run the code with the default solvers Gecode, Chuffed, it does shows me an output.

I am not sure what Minizinc library path to set up on my Preferences, I tired -Glienar, Ggecode. This might be the cause of the error

This is what shows me.

```
Compiling raid.mzn, with additional data raid_0.dzn

Running raid.mzn

Finished in 18msec
```

I am using Minizinc 2.1.6 in Linux-Ubuntu 16.04 SCIP 6.0.1, I tried with the latest version of Minizinc but none of the solvers worked.

Comment: How did you compile MiniZinc with SCIP?

Comment: Hi @Dekker1   I followed the below steps

Comment: #=============Scip Installation from directory
$ tar xvfz scipoptsuite-6.0.1.tgz
$ cd scipoptsuite-6.0.1
$ cd soplex
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make -j5
$ cd ../scip
$ mdkir build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -DSOPLEX_DIR=~/Downloads/Software/scipoptsuite-6.0.1/soplex/build
$ make -j5
$ sudo make install

Comment: That is the way to compile SCIP, but if you are using it with MiniZinc. You also have to recompile your MiniZinc and give the SCIP location. You might lose some other functionality if you don't compile with only SCIP and not the solvers included by MiniZinc

Comment: Hi @Dekker1 Thank you very much for helping me with my question, I followed the installation of adding Third-Party Solvers 3.2.5.2 on the Manual. Name=SCIP  Solver ID = scip  Version = 6.0.1 Executable = Minizinc/scipoptsuite-6.0.1/scip/build/bin/scip Solver Library path = "I do not have anything in here", do you know if my problem is that I am missing the last step? In that case, do you know where can I find it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The section on Third-Party solvers in the MiniZinc handbook describes how to add solvers that support FlatZinc instances. To my knowledge, SCIP can not read FlatZinc instance files. The only way I know to use SCIP is to recompile the MiniZinc driver/compiler with SCIP included in the driver.